# Extending an Excel VBA Macro code to display all the required information from data sheet

Tags: excel, vba, search, sapb1

thank you for clicking and spending your time. I will do my best to keep it short and clear.

The following code was written by a former employee who has left the company. I have no experience in VBA coding but I want to understand it to change this code to expand the use of the macro.

The macro compares an input string (item number) that is entered via scanning of a barcode (item label). The barcode contains the needed item number at the same place always - for which the "limiter" was set. Once the item number is entered, the macro searches to find the same item number in an excel sheet which pulls data from a SAP B1 query. An item number can be present in multiple lines in the data with different information (values) related to the same item. Currently, though, I only get one line returned and therefore only partial information, while other lines are ignored.

Here is the code:

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

limiter_a = "^#01^"
limiter_b = "^#02^"

End Sub


Private Sub suchbutton_Click()

Dim fullstring, searchstring As String
Dim partfound, locationfound, partqtyinfound As String
Dim partnotein, partspecialin, lastbin As String
Dim columnpart, columnlocation, lineqtydetail As String
Dim ergebnis As String
Dim j As Long
Dim lenght_a, lenght_b As Long

columnpart = "L"
columnlocation = "C"
partqtyinfound = "M"
partnotein = "O"
partspecialin = "P"
lastbin = "B"
lineqtydetail = "N"

lenght_a = Len(limiter_a)
lenght_b = Len(limiter_b)

fullstring = SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value

openPos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_a)
closePos = InStr(fullstring, limiter_b)


If openPos > "0" And closePos > "0" Then
    searchstring = Mid(fullstring, openPos + lenght_a, closePos - openPos - lenght_b)
Else
    ergebnis = "Keine Limiter gefunden"
End If


If ergebnis = "Keine Limiter gefunden" Then

    SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ergebnis
    SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
    SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.partnotein = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.partspecialin = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.lastbin = ""
    Suche.Teilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""

Else
'# I suspect the following part is the location where I need to expand the coding..

    letzteZeileTeilenummer = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = letzteZeileTeilenummer To 2 Step -1
        
        If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
            SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnpart & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ActiveSheet.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ActiveSheet.Range(partnotein & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ActiveSheet.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ActiveSheet.Range(lastbin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ActiveSheet.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value
            
            ergebnis = "Wert gefunden"
            
            Exit For
            
        Else
            ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden"
        End If
        
    Next j

End If

        If ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden" Then
            SucheTeilenummer.partfound = searchstring
            SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ""
            SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""
            
        End If

SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value = ""
fullstring = ""
ergebnis = ""
SucheTeilenummer.userinput.SetFocus


End Sub

Private Sub userinput_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
    Call suchbutton_Click
    KeyCode = 0
End If

End Sub


Private Sub userinput_change()
If InStr(SucheTeilenummer.userinput.Value, limiter_b) Then
    Call suchbutton_Click
End If

End Sub
```

First Image I've attached displays the output.

[[image]]

The item qty is summarized in total, which is 6. However, the item has 2 data lines due to there being different item characteristics to different quantities. Example: 1 item is set with a 300 Bar range, while 5 are set with 325 Bar. This is the data I am trying to fully consider and display when these differences occur. The differing values can change from numeric bar ranges, or just different sales employee names that need to be contacted for the corresponding item. It could be 2 lines or up to 12 lines for one single item, with differences in related info.

[[image]]

The second image I attached is what I would like to achieve. I need the TextBox at the bottom to 1. show all relevant information summarized (somehow) and 2. I need it to change color for attention of the employee - whenever it is the case that there are different information.

I hope was able to explain it properly.

Sorry for all that text.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess here.
We need to delete the Exit For to make sure it keeps searching. Then make sure the Quantity detail merges with the next data.

```
Else
'# I suspect the following part is the location where I need to expand the coding..

    letzteZeileTeilenummer = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = letzteZeileTeilenummer To 2 Step -1
        
        If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
            SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnpart & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ActiveSheet.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ActiveSheet.Range(partnotein & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ActiveSheet.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ActiveSheet.Range(lastbin & j).Value
            SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ActiveSheet.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range(partnotein & j).Value & vbNewLine & SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail  
            ' I'm guessing above that partnotein is the +++ 325 BAR +++, if not replace with where that data is.
            
            ergebnis = "Wert gefunden"
            
            'Exit For
            
        Else
            ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden"
        End If
        
    Next j

End If
```

As a little bonus tip I will advice you to replace all ActiveSheet with Sheets("SheetName") or even better ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName").
Or create a variable to it:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetName")
```

and then use it in the code you have like this:

```
SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ws.Range(columnpart & j).Value
```

It might seem trivial and unnecessary but if you only knew how much damage ActiveSheet and ActiveWorkbook can do.

Comment: Thank you for the help. It has in fact worked, coupled with what Chris has contributed. I also cleared the ActiveSheet minefield as you suggested. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the German language in your code, but you are right, that it is your For Next loop that stops looking for additional lines that match.

I would create a boolean variable (eg booFOUND) to mark as True when a matching entry is found and then use it to set the value of your ergebnis string after completing the loop:

```
    If ergebnis = "Keine Limiter gefunden" Then
        SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ergebnis
        SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ""
        SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ""
        Suche.Teilenummer.partnotein = ""
        Suche.Teilenummer.partspecialin = ""
        Suche.Teilenummer.lastbin = ""
        Suche.Teilenummer.lineqtydetail = ""

    Else
    '# I suspect the following part is the location where I need to expand the coding..

        letzteZeileTeilenummer = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, columnpart).End(xlUp).Row
        For j = letzteZeileTeilenummer To 2 Step -1
    
            If Range(columnpart & j).Value = searchstring Then
                booFOUND = True

                SucheTeilenummer.partfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnpart & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.locationfound = ActiveSheet.Range(columnlocation & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partqtyinfound = ActiveSheet.Range(partqtyinfound & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partnotein = ActiveSheet.Range(partnotein & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.partspecialin = ActiveSheet.Range(partspecialin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lastbin = ActiveSheet.Range(lastbin & j).Value
                SucheTeilenummer.lineqtydetail = ActiveSheet.Range(lineqtydetail & j).Value
            End If            
        Next j

        If booFOUND Then
            ergebnis = "Wert gefunden"
        Else
            ergebnis = "Wert nicht gefunden"
        End If

    End If
```

The caveat is that I haven't tried to understand what the SucheTeilenumber lines are for, so it may be that these need to be summed or stored in array variables, so you will need to look at these and amend, but this sort of thing should allow you to check all lines.

Comment: Thanks. It was indeed the solution, coupled with Andreas has contributed. I will try to clean up small problems on my own. This was very helpful.